# AngularJS controller event after all $watch executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, watch

It is possible to fire one event (only one time) after all controller matchers execute?

For example:

```
$scope.$watch 'var1', (value) ->
  # Do something ...
  callEvent()

$scope.$watch 'var2', (value) ->
  # Do something ...
  callEvent()

$scope.$watch 'var3', (value) ->
  # Do something ...
  callEvent()

$scope.$watch 'var4', (value) ->
  # Do something ...
  callEvent()
```

In my case callEvent() fired 4 times, but I need only one time.

I also can change my business app logic, but it will be in very long term.

Answer (score 1):

One way is with an extra, deep watch (don't know CS, code will be in JS):

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return {
            var1: $scope.var1,
            var2: $scope.var2,
            var3: $scope.var3,
            var4: $scope.var4
        };
    },
    function(newval) {
        callEvent();
    },
    true // deep watch
);
```

Note that again the event will be fired once per digest cycle!

Another way would be to use a flag - it will need to be reset with a timeout (ugly):

```
var flag = false;

$scope.$watch('var1', function(newval) {
    // Do something
    callEventOnce();
});

// same for var2, 3, 4

function callEventOnce() {
    if( !flag ) {
        flag = true;
        $timeout(function() {
            flag = false;
        });
        callEvent();
    }
}
```

**One way to escape the ugliness of the timeout is to make the controller listen to the event and then reset the flag.** E.g., if the `callEvent()` is implemented as:

```
// HYPOTHETICAL IMPLEMENTATION OF callEvent()
function callEvent() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('my_event');
}
```

Add this to the controller:

```
$scope.$on('my_event', function() {
    flag = false;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this call the event after one of the watcher triggers? OP wants it to fire when *all* watchers triggered.

Comment: My understanding of the question is "how to fire something after any number (1 or more) of changes", not necessarily all. But the (silent) OP is responsible for clarifying this...

Answer (score 1):

How about use Promise?

```
watchNames = 'var1 var2 var3 var4'.split(' ')
watchDefers = {}

eventHandler = ->
  # do what you want

  initDefers()

initDefers = ->
  watchNames.forEach (varName) ->
    watchDefers[varName] = $q.defer()

  watchPromiseArray = watchNames.map (varName) ->
    watchDefers[varName].promise

  $q.all(watchPromiseArray).then eventHandler

$scope.$watch 'var1', (value) ->
  watchDefers.var1.resolve()

$scope.$watch 'var2', (value) ->
  watchDefers.var2.resolve()

$scope.$watch 'var3', (value) ->
  watchDefers.var3.resolve()

$scope.$watch 'var4', (value) ->
  watchDefers.var4.reolsve()

initDefers()
```

Comment: I'd save a reference to the watchers (`watchers.push $scope.$watch ...`) to be able to destroy them later since they're only needed once. (`watcher() for watcher in watchers`)

Answer (score 0):

Your `watchExpression` is bound to those `var*` strings; you need to have (a `boolean` for instance) added to the same, so it will be something like your `var*` and a `boolean`; change the `boolean` value after successful execution.

Another approach is to change the `watchExpression` itselft, but that's a little tricky and *obscure*; and another one could be to unbind your `$watch` listener(s).

Good luck and let me know if you happen to have a better/different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watchGroup`

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'], function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // your code here
});
```

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope
http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-watch-watchgroup-and-watchcollection-methods-of-scope